# How to modify a URL in a cypress test?

Tags: automation, javascript, cypress

I have a Cypress test that I wrote, and to avoid writing a second test, I'd like to be able to take the resulting URL, and do two things with it:

1) I'd like to modify it to force it to another page

2) While doing #1, I'll also need to extract a dynamic value from the URL to be used in the modified URL.

I have cy.url() but I don't know how to capture the value I need and set it as a variable. Does anyone know of a way to do this? I'm a new coder and still learning javascript so this might be easy and I just don't know how to go about it. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are looking for the variables section of the cypress documentation https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Debugging

Answer (score 5):

To extract values from cy elements, you must use promises [(then syntax)](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Syntax).
Working with JS asynchronicity is a bit daunting at first, but do not panic!
Study this core concept and you will quickly learn how Cypress works!

To answer question #1, you could do:

```
cy.url().then(urlValue => cy.visit(urlValue + '/about');
```

The example above will extract the current url and you can use it in the next action.
(url is exposed as an arrow function argument, here called urlValue).

Comment: what if I want to modify cy.url in component test? is there any equal cy.visit syntax in component test?